# How do I get rid of, obsolete cipher suite issue in google chrome with JBOSS configuration

Tags: java, google-chrome, ssl, https, jboss

We have deployed our web application developed in java, in JBOSS application server. We have applied SSL for the application. Everything looks fine, but when I open the application in google chrome, it shows me a message as sown in below image. (I have shaded the domain name as it is clients application and I can't disclose it)

[image]

I have done lot of googling and found that this is an issue because of the cipher suite configuration in JBOSS configuration file. I have tried including  "`AES_128_GCM or CHACHA20_POLY1305`" suggested by google chrome but didn't work.
I have tried replacing lot of ciphers but nothing resolved the problem for me. 
I have found the solution for the similar issue in Apache web server. But I didn't find any solution for JBOSS. Hence I am writing this question. Below is my https connector configuration in JBOSS standalone.xml file

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
 <ssl name="myssl" key-alias="1" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/amc.jks" cipher-suite="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"/>  </connector>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve my issue. The Problem was because of using Java 7. Java 7 does not support AES_128_GCM cipher (Which is treated as modern cipher by Chrome). I have upgraded my Java Version to Java 8. Now since Java 8 supports AES_128_GCM obsolete cipher suite message has changed to modern cipher suite.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` soon after `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, still it is same. This is my cipher suite now cipher-suite="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"